# Understanding t-distribution proof

Tags: statistics

Below is an image of the proof of $T = \frac{\bar{}Y-\mu}{S/\sqrt{n}} \sim t_{n-1} $

[image: Proof here]

I don't understand how the third line becomes the fourth line.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

1. $\dfrac \sigma s$ is the reciprocal of $\dfrac{1}{s/\sigma}$
2. $a\equiv\sqrt{a^2}$ if $a\ge 0$